# Why cant I open CDF's in the Chrome browser on Linux?

Tags: cdf-format, linux

I have google chrome on ubuntu 13.04. Every time I try to run a CDF on wolframs website, I'm required to download the CDF first, and then open it in my computer, but when I was using windows it was ready to use on the browser itself, any ideas on how to fix it? Is it a better topic for the ubuntu stackexchange?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for rushing and posting the question, I ended up finding the answer in wolfram CDF player website.

The linux version currently does not support the web plugin.

Source: http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/supported-platforms.html

Comment: Please add a link to the answer you found at the Wolfram site.